# How to disable mouse wheel scrolling with xinput?

Tags: xinput, mouse-wheel

`xinput` says my mouse is id 11:

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VirtualBox mouse integration              id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse           id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Setting buttons 4 and 5 to 0 works:

```
$ xinput --set-button-map 11 1 2 3 0 0 6 7 8 9
$ xinput --get-button-map 11
1 2 3 0 0 6 7 8 9
```

However, mouse wheel scrolling is not disabled. Any ideas what to do about it? Ubuntu 18.04.3.

**ETA**: Please note that the answer accepted in [How to disable mouse wheel scroll in ubuntu 11.04 or 10.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59128/how-to-disable-mouse-wheel-scroll-in-ubuntu-11-04-or-10-10) does not work, at least in my case.

**ETA2**: Added as per request:

```
$ xinput list-props 11
Device 'ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse':
    Device Enabled (127):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (129): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (266):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (267):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (274):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (275):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (276):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (277): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (278): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (279):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (280):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (281): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (282): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (283):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (284):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (285):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (270): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (271): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (249): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (250):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (251):    0, 0
    Device Node (252):  "/dev/input/event4"
    Device Product ID (253):    2, 6
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (272):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (273):   1
```

Comment: similar question ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/59128/how-to-disable-mouse-wheel-scroll-in-ubuntu-11-04-or-10-10

Comment: Except that the answer in it does not work.

Comment: Post output of `xinput list-props 11`

Comment: @Pilot6 Here you are.

Comment: So libinput is used. It doesn't have those options. Need to switch pack to `evdev`.

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution?

Comment: @teg_brightly I did not find any solution. However, I learned an important thing about Ubuntu in the years passed: it does not necessarily work even out of the box. Trying to configure it in a nontrivial (hence even more untested) way is utterly pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `libinput` by

```
sudo apt remove 'xserver-xorg-input-libinput.*'
```

The mouse will be handled by `evdev` and all former solutions will work.

Comment: Admittedly, I'm somewhat wary of the possibility to break some other part of the system with it.

Comment: You won't break anything by this and you can always install it back.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it tomorrow unless someone suggests a less intrusive solution. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Tried it. Breaks the system completely as expected: mouse cursor stuck, keyboard dead. Of course, I had a VirtualBox snapshot at ready.