# Replacement for a trivial Autohotkey script

Tags: software-recommendation, remapping

This no-brainer has been running on my Windows systems since XP:

```
WheelUp::return
WheelDown::return
$NumpadSub::Send {WheelUp}
$NumpadAdd::Send {WheelDown}
```

Basically, it blocks the broken wheel of my ancient but otherwise serviceable mouse and allows me to use <kbd>NumAdd</kbd> and <kbd>NumSub</kbd> instead. What I tried to replace it on Ubuntu with:

1. `xbindkeys` + `xdotool`. Mouse wheel blocking works but mouse wheel emulation does not: 'clicks' emulated by `xdotool` get blocked by `xbindkeys` too.
2. `xmodmap`. All kinds of weird side effects. People say it is deprecated and should not be used.
3. `xinput`. Does not work at all, supposedly because of a conflict with `libevent`. Removing the latter [as advised on this site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178459/how-to-disable-mouse-wheel-scrolling-with-xinput) disabled my keyboard and mouse completely.
4. Took a look at `xkb` but could not find any actionable documentation.

Overall, I'm at a loss and thus request something like a solution. Ubuntu 18.04.3.