# How to disable mouse scroll wheel in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: mouse, mouse-scroll

I see this question has already an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59128/how-to-disable-mouse-wheel-scroll-in-ubuntu-11-04-or-10-10). But it didn't work for 20.04. What might be the solution for 20.04 version?

Comment: Did you try the mouse and keyboard settings under settings? Why do you want to disable it?

Comment: My scroll wheel doesn't work properly, It scrolls on its own!